# Two web applications each with their own IP

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

We have a newly-configured Sharepoint 2013 server installation, which serves our company Intranet. The new Intranet web application is now in service and operational. It uses the internal IP address of the sharepoint machine, e.g 192.168.100.10, on port 80.

Now, we need to create another top-level site which will serve as an Extranet portal for a client; this extranet site will not require SSL. The content, configuration and users will be different, hence the need for a separate web application. We already have another internal IP bound to the Sharepoint server's network config, e.g. 192.168.100.11.

The "simple" task we want to achieve is to create a separate web application in Sharepoint using 192.168.100.11. However, Sharepoint Central Administration apparently does not provide a method by which a separate IP address can be selected for a new web application; instead, it provides port selection or entry only.

We plan to route external client traffic to the extranet site, which requires either a mapped internal IP address or a different port. Our public-sector client cannot use a non-standard port due to their firewall restrictions. Furthermore, our company SOP's do not allow host header usage in IIS. So, this means a unique IP.

In the exhaustive research conducted concerning this issue, we have not been able to find examples of this scenario. We have researched literally hundreds of blog posts and articles, all of which describe SSL wildcards, host header implementation or the use of non-standard ports.

We want to do something that appears to be the simplest, most logical way to proceed, except that we cannot find the steps necessary to do it.

Question: what is the correct way of achieving our goal?

Answer (score 1):

To bind the web application to a specific address you have to change the bindings in IIS. Create the web app as normal then go and update the bindings

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone arrives here looking for the answer to this issue, we decided just to create a new virtual machine and host the extranet on that one, using another sharepoint installation. It is considered ill-advised to attempt the complex configuration required to create the scenario we needed, due to the labor-intensive research process which ultimately proved to be fruitless.

Answer (score 0):

You should add an "A" record in your DNS server first. Navigate to your  Windows server which hosts the DNS server role and launch Server Manager and then click on Tools > DNS Manager. Expand your Forward Lookup Zones and create a new “A” record and enter the name you want for your server and then the IP address.  Please note, you shall add a new “A” record and not a CNAME (Alias) record.

Then, you will be able to create a new Web Application using this name as your host header.